# Picking a specific bookmark based on a RLS filtered value in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, bookmarks, row-level-security

I need help with Power BI utility of Bookmarking.

Suppose, i have a power bi report embedded in a website and based on RLS and roles, it is filtered to a specific user. So if the dashboard does not contain any data for a particular user, all my visuals tend to show "blanks". And i feel it is not an elegant way to show this scenario.

So i figured adding a "Card" that says "No Data available" to the report page and was fiddling around with trying to bring this forward or backwards and i didnt have success with it.

I was thinking along the route of having bookmarked page with card visual selected first in the tab order. But i am stuck trying to make the bookmarked page come up when a role that has no data in the dashboard is picked up.

I know i must use a Measure to get it done. I would really appreciate if someone is getting an idea to help me out.

Also, to the above scenario i mentioned, if there is any other solution that can be applied, i would like to know about it too.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF!

You can create a measure to handle the blank values.
For example, the below measure checks if the value is blank and attests your requirement of "No Data Available" and if not blank displays the actual number.

```
NewMeasure= IF(CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Clients[fldPersonID]), FILTER(Clients, Clients[Has Paid= 1)) = BLANK(), "No Data Available", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Clients[fldPersonID]), FILTER(Clients, Clients[Has Paid=] = 1)))
```

Let me know how you go. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the measure. I did try a similar calculated measure to handle this. The problem i have is that there are 7-8 visuals in my report page and i want a card to be displayed above all them whenever there is "No Data" after the filtering process. So i figured having a bookmarked page would be rather good than having to change all the visuals.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to display a bookmarked page with selected visuals based on a condition or measure??